# Python 3 script crash on lru_cache

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have raspberry pi acting as MFRC522 card reader. So far I have a script which worked on python 2.7, but when I tried to move to python 3, bizarre thing happened.

- I used updated library for it: https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python and adjusted my script accordingly
- I installed pip3 and spidev
- Here is where strange thing happens. If I run demo script from repo above in new folder it works, cool.
- But if I put my previous script in the same folder it returns error as below. And after that if I try again to run demo script, same error occurs.
- Moving both script to different folder, has the same effect. I can run demo only before my script. Doing that after, is impossible.

Error:

```py
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 297, in <module>
    @functools.lru_cache(_MAXCACHE)
AttributeError: module 'functools' has no attribute 'lru_cache'
```

My script:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import time
import requests
import signal
import sys
import os

# some functions non related to MFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

while continue_reading:
    try:

        id, text = reader.read()
        #print id
        #print "---"

        ver = query_server(id)
        if ver == 1:
            open_relay(5)

        else:
            #do something

    finally:
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

It's like folder is somehow tainted after firing my script, what am I missing?

Comment: Try to look here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9344